# samsung mobile mtp device failed to install

Tags: android, tablet, device-driver, samsung-mobile

I am trying to test my android application on a samsung s2 phone with android version 4.0.3, I downloaded the usb driver from the official website, but the program does not detect the phone, returning a message telling me that samsung mobile mtp device failed

any help please?

Comment: have you installed kies?

Comment: This should be on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes i did install kies, but still same problem

Comment: Given that the goal is enable ADB in order to test an application being developed, the question would nominally belong here, though there may be useful expertise on the android usage site.  At any rate, you should not actually need a working MTP driver to have a ADB connection and deploy an app.  For that matter, if you know the app is close to working, in a pinch you could just email the apk to an account on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have followed the Exact steps from Link : http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/559858-samsung-mobile-mtp-device-cannot-installed.html

Here are steps :  (for Windows specific instructions):

1. Ensure phone is not connected to PC.
2. Uninstall KIES from PC. Reboot your PC and Reinstall KIES after that. Just for great measure... open KIES, go to Tools | Troubleshoot connection error. Follow instructions and wait for it to finish the troubleshooting procedure.
3. Reboot your phone (or turn off and then on your phone again). Do not connect it to your PC just yet.
4. Once rebooted, go to your phone's dialer, type *#7284# - A configuration window will appear. In that window's USB section, if it's default to PDA, tap MODEM, then back to PDA, (if it is MODEM in the beginning, change it to PDA) then press the back key to exit. Most importantly, it must set as PDA when you exit.
5. Turn off USB debugging in your phone.
6. (Optional) Set your phone's screen timeout to a lengthy time. (minimum 1-2 minutes - recommended 5mins to 30mins) its found in Settings | Display. You can change this back later on.
7. Connect the phone to your PC with USB cable and let windows load your drivers... and wait for the drivers to get reinstalled.
8. Once reinstalled, disconnect the phone off USB. Switch USB debugging back on in your phone settings, and reconnect the phone back - you'll see windows load another set of drivers for your phone. Wait until it is completed. (This step is a precautionative measure to ensure your phone is identified with all the necessary drivers)
9. Once complete, unplug your phone, and turn off USB debugging... This is to ensure MTP will initialize. Also, press the phone's home key until your homescreen is displayed. Only after doing all that, reconnect your phone back to PC.
10. Test and see if MTP works using Windows Explorer. You'll see your phone's USB storage and SDCard contents if it does.

This definitely helped me after 2 days of googling..... Hope it will help others too....

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a slightly different procedure with my SCH-S738C Samsung phone.  Here are the steps I took to get the phone communicating with Windows XP:

1. Ensure phone is not connected to PC.
2. Uninstall KIES from PC. Reboot your PC and Reinstall KIES after that. Just for great
   measure... open KIES, go to Tools | Troubleshoot connection error. Follow instructions
   and wait for it to finish the troubleshooting procedure.
3. On your SCH-S738C Samsung phone type into google search: [root SCH-S738C].  This will
   bring up the following web address:
   http://forums.droidbeans.com/tutorials/(how-to)(root-micromax-qualcomm-phones-without-pc)/?action=thankyoupostlist;msg=813
   then navigate to this address.
4. On your SCH-S738C Samsung phone select the poot.apk from the spot on the page that
   reads: Download poot.apk.
5. Follow the rest of the instructions on the web page, which are:
   1) Download and Install poot.apk
   2) Now open the poot app then it will require you to install Ministro II, Simply
      follow the link to Google play store.
   3) Then you will be required to update ministro library, please update it.
   4) Once you updated the Ministro Library then you will be faced with two options;
       1. “Press here to Poot”
       2. “Built in root check”
   5) Click on the first option which is “Press here to Poot” and after a while,
      You are going to face with three options.
       1. Get Superuser
       2. Get root-checker
       3. In-built rootchecker
   When you see these options it simply means your phone has been rooted
   successfully. Then click get Superuser to complete the process..
   6) And finally do a reboot to take effect :P
   7) Congrats you have rooted your phone now
6. Ensure Samsung Kies is running on your Windows XP machine.
7. Connect the phone to your PC with USB cable and let windows load your drivers...
   and wait for the drivers to get reinstalled.

I was now able to stop Samsung Kies and just use Windows XP File Manager to load and copy files to and from the SCH-738C Samsung phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Samsung devices when I installed fresh Windows XP. I figured out that I cannot install "SAMSUNG Mobile MTP Device Driver" over Windows update site so I:

1. Download drivers from
   http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewRedirect.aspx?updateid=523dde6f-6efb-47ac-9aac-8f53732e45c9
2. Connect device to the PC
3. When Windows notifies about new HW I installed drivers from downloaded package (for USB, MTP etc)
4. adb works fine but still device was not visible over MTP so I installed Windows Media Plaery 11 over Windows Update

That solved the problem. WMP 11 is required for the MTP mode. Otherwise Samsung Kies would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Samsung Kies software, on top left of the window, click the menu > Driver recovery.
Let it reinstall drivers
After driver installation finished, go to your phone, Settings> Application > Development, tick USB debugging mode.
Under USB debugging mode connect your phone to the PC with USB.
It installs correctly!
Disconnect from PC
Untick USB debugging mode
Connect again