# Unable to connect Samsung Galaxy Tab2 GT- P3100 to PC

Tags: android, usb, driver, samsung-mobile

I am unable to connect my `Samsung galaxy tab 2(GT-P3100)` to my Computer , as I am `android` developer and want to test app in it.

It shows error message as:

`Device Driver software was not successfully installed.`

`Samsung Mobile MTP Device failed.`

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no proper usb port in the Tab 2. How did you connect to PC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have followed the Exact steps from Link :

1. **[`Samsung mobile MTP Device cannot be installed`](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/559858-samsung-mobile-mtp-device-cannot-installed.html)**
2. StackOverflow **[`tutorial`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221198/2123594)**

Here are steps : `for Windows specific instructions`:

1. Ensure phone is not connected to PC.
2. Uninstall KIES from PC. Reboot your PC and Reinstall KIES after that. Just for great measure... open KIES, go to `Tools | Troubleshoot connection error`. Follow instructions and wait for it to finish the troubleshooting procedure.
3. Reboot your phone (or turn off and then on your phone again). **`Do not connect it to your PC just yet.`**
4. Once rebooted, go to your phone's dialer, type **`*#7284#`** - A configuration window will appear. In that window's USB section, if it's default to PDA, tap MODEM, then back to PDA, (if it is MODEM in the beginning, change it to PDA) then press the back key to exit. Most importantly, it must set as PDA when you exit.
5. Turn off USB debugging in your phone.
6. (Optional) Set your phone's screen timeout to a lengthy time. (minimum 1-2 minutes - recommended 5mins to 30mins) its found in Settings | Display. You can change this back later on.
7. Connect the phone to your PC with USB cable and let windows load your drivers... and wait for the drivers to get reinstalled.
8. Once reinstalled, disconnect the phone off USB. Switch USB debugging back on in your phone settings, and reconnect the phone back - you'll see windows load another set of drivers for your phone. Wait until it is completed. (This step is a precautionative measure to ensure your phone is identified with all the necessary drivers)
9. Once complete, unplug your phone, and turn off USB debugging... This is to ensure MTP will initialize. Also, press the phone's home key until your homescreen is displayed. Only after doing all that, reconnect your phone back to PC.
10. Test and see if MTP works using Windows Explorer. You'll see your phone's USB storage and SDCard contents if it does.

Hope it will help you..

Answer (score 3):

First download the driver from:
  [Samsung driver...](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/GT-P3100TSENPL-downloads?downloadName=SW)

Then if you face a problem.. update your question...

Comment: Hi Amal, I have download Kies s/w and try to connect to Tab, but it is not responding. I think device driver is not properly installed over here. How can i get MTP USB device driver ?

Comment: Even i am not able to find out the issue.. When i get any error like this.. i reinstall the drivers and reboot.. It may work for you too.. And again its not a perfect solution.. Its better for u if you ask this question in samsung mobile forums...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I did an abbreviated version of Swapnil's instructions and it worked...

I unhooked my device, reinstalled Kies, rebooted my device and unchecked usb debugging.  Then I reconnected it and it successfully installed the drivers.  At that point I rechecked USB debugging and now everything is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this.

goto Settings --> Developer Options --> USB Debugging and check it .

It should probably work..